# Javascript : Loading images via Javascript 

Tags: javascript, html, image

This is a chunk of javascript code from a tutorial where  they are trying to load an image onto a canvas and do some manipulations later on. I have omitted most of the irrelevant code to make it simpler to understand.

1) I fail to understand why the line containing the filename of the image is always put below the imageObj.onload function . Does it matter ? At what point does the image start getting loaded ?

2) What will happen if I forget to put the source of the image file.

```
<script>
            window.onload = function(){
                ....

                var imageObj = new Image();

                imageObj.onload = function(){
                    ....
                    ....
                    });

                    ....
                    ....

                };
                imageObj.src = "yoda.jpg";

            };
        </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried not putting the source of the image file to see what will happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a somewhat historical issue. The order from `.onload` and `.src` doesn't really matter (it'll work technically on both orders), the issue is that some browsers (some = Internet Explorers) will take the image from the cache if available, as soon as the `src` attribute is set.

That is why you should always declare an `onload` handler before setting `src`.

If you just forget to set the `src` attribute, just nothing will happen at all. If you don't hold any more references or closures to that object, it will just get garbage collected as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Loading is triggered by setting the `.src` property.

On (some?) older browsers, the handler is not called if it's registered after the property is set, especially if the image was already in cache and therefore "loaded" immediately.

If you forget to set the attribute, nothing will ever happen.

Comment: It'll also work in all browsers if you switch the order from `.onload` and `.src`. The order is most likely because of caching issues with InternetExplorers, which take the image from the cache as soon as `.src` is beeing set.

Comment: @jAndy please make you comment an answer, because all three answers given here are wrong regarding that point.

Comment: @jAndy yes, that's strictly correct, but we do still have to support old MSIE versions, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 2):

```
window.onload = function(){
                // This is function 1 
                // This portion will execute when window has loaded completely.
                // In simple words, page has been downloaded completely.

                var imageObj = new Image();

                imageObj.onload = function(){
                    // This is function 2
                   // This portion will execute when image has loaded completely 
                    });

                    ....
                    ....

                };
                imageObj.src = "yoda.jpg";
```

So, function 1 and function 2 will execute after this line  `imageObj.src = "yoda.jpg";`

This is answer to your first question. Putting it below does not means, it will execute after function 2. In javascript, code executes sequentially from top to bottom, but code inside functions will only execute when that function is called.

If you wont give `src` attribute, there would be no image to download, and thus function 2 wont get called.

Answer (score 0):

Loading starting when you set `src` attribute. And `img.onload` function will be called after successful loading of the image.

Answer (score 0):

changing the `src` triggers the "loading sequence", and due to the nature of JS to sequentially execute, you *must* register the handler *before* you load the image.

not changing the `src` will not trigger the loading sequence.